# How to show loader while loading image using file path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android, flutter-image, flutter-file

How to show loader before loading complete image from file? Before loading image in Imageview it takes some time before image is visible to user.

```
Image.file(
  File(selectedImagePath),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: double.infinity,
 ),
```

Comment: use `Image` constructor instead of `Image.file` - it has `ImageLoadingBuilder? loadingBuilder,` parameter

Comment: @pskink If you any example to refer then please share link or code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @pskink
You can use Image constructor

```
Image(
      image: FileImage(
      File(selectedImagePath)),
         width: double.infinity,
         height: double.infinity,
         loadingBuilder:
             (context, child, loadingProgress) {
             if (loadingProgress == null) {
                 debugPrint('image loading null');
                 return child;
             }
             debugPrint('image loading...');
             return const Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
       ),
```